# JDBC Update query error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't execute the update query on  JDBC with where clause.  I want to execute the query by concatenating some variables.

```
protected void updateEmail(String Email, String Username) {
    try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project", "root", "");

        String query = "update access set email=" + Email + " where username=" + Username;

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

It says:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bhusal1' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: this makes no sense. you don't have that column name in your query. is that the value you pass as parameter?

Comment: I do have coloum with username bhusal1.

Comment: "update access set email="+Email+" where username=" ... in this query, you have email and username as columnnames, not buhsal1. but YCF_L is right.

Comment: The answer provided by @YCF_L is a better way to do it. However, the problem with your code is simply that you forgot the quotes... 

`String query = "update access set email='" + Email + "' where username='" + Username + "'";`

Comment: I tried that too. String query = "update access set email='" + Email + "' where username='" + Username + "'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String should be between two quotes `'name'` instead of your way you have to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead to avoid syntax error or SQL Injection :

```
String query = "update access set email=? where username=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

ps.setString(1, email);
ps.setString(2, name);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How can i execute that?

Comment: what did you mean @suryabhusal you can use `ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: Thanks i though there might  be other method. Din't tried that. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L. I was familiar with Prepared Statement in PHP but din't know on Java. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with concatenation of the request. The approach you use is extremely bad and can cause any problems (including security).

To avoid problems, use `PrepareStatement` when you need to submit sql query parameters.
Here's an example that should solve your problem:

```
void updateEmail(String email,String username) {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project", "root", "")) {
        String query = "update access set email = ? where username = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, email);
            statement.setString(2, username);

            statement.executeUpdate();
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your variables email and username between quotes in the where clause to be able to do the update query

Comment: Welcome to Stack. For future reference, when giving an answer its best if you include some code and explain the answer more thoroughly.

Comment: This leaves the OP open to SQL injection. Don't give bad advice, even if it technically works.

Comment: Okay , thank you both for the advice guys , im gonna try to do it better in the following answers :)

Comment: Why not do better with this answer, you can still edit it to improve it.